# Как обращатся к одной из нескольких бд yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

**Здравствуйте.**
У меня есть две абсолютно одинаковые по структуре базы данных, но в них разные записи. Как реализоваться выборку из одной из таких баз данных.

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге добавляете еще одну бд, например db2 и в модели указываете:

```
public static function getDb()
{
    return \Yii::$app->get('db2');
}
```